# Ninject, MVC and Session Scope: Reasonable Practice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, ninject

I'm building an MVC3 app with Entity Framework where almost all of the actions are only allowed to authorized users. Consequently, I have a frequent need to reference a Member entity. I've experimented with different ways of caching the Member, and have come up with an approach which is pretty fast. But I'd like some advice/perspective on the risks/downsides of what I'm doing.

I've defined a factory class for retrieving the Member instance which is "registered" with Ninject so I can use it wherever I need it. The Ninject binding is "session scoped" (I'll explain that in a moment). The factory method first checks Session to see if it contains a previously-created instance of Member. If Session doesn't the routine creates an instance from the underlying database via EF, storing the value in Session as well as returning it.

Because some of the accesses against the Member instance are EF calls I had to ensure the EF object context was also in session scope (I learned the hard way that calling EF routines against a Member instance which was originally created under a different context doesn't work too well). Since the factory and the object context are created via Ninject I had to define a Session scope for Ninject.

I found a code snippet to do that [here](http://iridescence.no/post/Session-Scoped-Bindings-With-Ninject-2.aspx) which I was able to modify to meet my needs. But it's such a simple snippet that I wonder if there's a reason the capability's not provided "natively" by Ninject (or Ninject MVC). Which makes me wonder if I'm courting trouble by what I'm doing.

I do realize there are a number of aspects of storing stuff in Session that you have to program around, chief among which is the fact that the stored object can "disappear" at any time (i.e., you always have to have a way to recreate it when you get it). But while that adds enough complexity that I wouldn't want to do it for a lot of objects, doing it for a single Member object isn't all that difficult.

In any event, advice and feedback on session-scoping an Ninject binding and storing EF entities in Session for an MVC app would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several reasons there is no such scope in Ninject itself:

- The implementation makes it impossible to scale the application. While it is possible to share the session between several instances of IIS, the data in your session scope can not because every IIS instance has its own Ninject kernel.
- It would encourage users to use it in large scale. But generally it is not a good idea to put data into a session unless absolutely necessary because it is cached for a long time and there is no mechanism to get it out of the memory before the session times out. This can quickly lead to out of memory issues. Session data should be used very carefully for this reason.
- The prefered way for session scoped data is to add it to the session and add a transient binding to a method that returns this data or creates a new instance if it is not yet available. This way the data gets removed together with the session rather than keeping it in the memory for some additional time until Ninject releases it. Additionally, scaling of the application is supported this way.

There is no problem with your implementation Ninject-wise. But as I said before you have to be very carefully about putting data into session scope. I think you should also think about other ways to cache data that allow eviction of data before using this approach, e.g., with NHibernate I would suggest looking into level 2 caching. If you still decide to use session data, the better way is to put it into the session rather than having a Ninject session scope as it allows scaling of the application.